# Marked does not sanitize readme file in VueJS component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Can someone tell me why the response from `compiledMarkdown` function is not sanitized, and all content from md file has no style?

```
<template>
  <div style="padding:35px;">
    <div v-html="compiledMarkdown"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import marked from 'marked';

export default {
  components: {},
  data () {
    return {}
  },
  methods: {
    compiledMarkdown: function () {
      return marked(this.content, { sanitize: true });
    }
  },
  props: {
      content: {
          type: String
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please add the code of the parent component, and the result you get, so community can help you.

Comment: According to the [library documentation](https://marked.js.org/using_advanced#options), the `sanitize` option is deprecated.

Comment: @guyaloni is there any alternatives? can yous show maybe an example?

Comment: I think you have enough information in the documentation to check this out.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://marked.js.org/using_advanced#options) of the [marked component](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) say it very clear:

**'sanitize' option:**
Warning: This feature is deprecated and it should NOT be used as it cannot be considered secure.
Instead use a sanitize library, like [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) (recommended), [sanitize-html](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html) or [insane](https://github.com/bevacqua/insane) on the output HTML!

Probably this is why your text is not sanitized.